# (Properly) Link to custom Lightning App from record detail page?

Tags: custom-button, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, deep-linking

I have a custom lightning app.

How can I link to this app from a record's detail LEX page (e.g. Opportunity) and pass the Opp's ID to it?
The end-user is supposed to launch the app and do some additional Opportunity-stuff.

I've tried this so far:

1. Create a custom button (type = URL). Content:

   {!URLFOR('/c/OppAwesomizer.app?opp=' +  Opportunity.Id )}

The button/action shows up on the Opp's detail page (in LEX), but...

- It opens the custom App in an Iframe within the LEX UI.
- That does not work well if the browser does not like cross-domain iframe communications, because LEX itself works on: https://xyz.lightning.force.com/one/one.app..., but my custom button creates a URL for the iFrame like this: https://xyz.cs82.my.salesforce.com/servlet...

So e.g. my Chrome just displays a blank area and the console shows this message:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property
>   from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

2. Create a custom action to a LEX-enabled VF page that redirects to the app: Same behaviour as above...

Any help is greatly appreciated, I don't think SF has no way to achieve this but I have not been able to find anything on this...

Answer (score 0):

This works in a URL button, although it sometime gives a warning "We'd like to open the Salesforce page https://[myDomain].lightning.force.com... in a new tab. Because of your browser settings, we need your permission first."

```
/c/OppAwesomizer.app#{!Opportunity.Id}
```